# Update a label in Tkinter when pressing a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a "program" that updates a label when you press a button and print out a variable, but with the code i have it does not work. Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
x = 0


def test():
    global x
    x += 1
    label_1.update()

label_1 = Label(root, text=x)
button_1 = Button(root, text='Click', command=test)
button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label_1.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `label_1.update()` (which [doesn't do anything close to what you think it does](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method)), [reconfigure the widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method) with `label_1.config(text=x)`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution: using the `textvariable` tag along with a Tkinter IntVar.

Example:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
x = IntVar()


def test():
    global x
    x.set(x.get() + 1)

label_1 = Label(root, text=x.get(), textvariable = x)
button_1 = Button(root, text='Click', command=test)
button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label_1.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

*EDIT: Removed the `label_1.update()` call as it is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it as a class, which has numerous advantages...

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.x = tk.IntVar()

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.x).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Click', command=self.increment).pack()

    def increment(self):
        self.x.set(self.x.get() + 1)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```